# Can't access my fragment using findFragmentById

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to pass data in between fragments, but I can't access my fragment to get elements from it.
I have multiple fragments that are displayed in a FrameLayout in main.xml which id is 'content'.
They are controlled using Java.
Fragment layouts are in separate xml layout files.
How to access those fragments using findFragmentById method?
Or you could recommend something else.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator {

    // For fragments
    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    Fragment myFragment;
    Button about, list, settings;

    // Classes
    Methods method = new Methods();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Preparing fragments and UI
        list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
        about = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
        method.backgroundImageDefault(list);
        method.backgroundImageDefault(about);
        method.backgroundImageDefault(settings);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Welcome myFragment = new Welcome();
            ft.add(R.id.content, myFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        list.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        about.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        settings.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

    }

    // On Click listener for fragments
    Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment newFragment;

            if (v == list) {
                newFragment = new List();
                method.backgroundImageClicked(list, about, settings);
            } else if (v == about) {
                newFragment = new About();
                method.backgroundImageClicked(about, list, settings);
            } else if (v == settings) {
                newFragment = new Settings();
                method.backgroundImageClicked(settings, about, list);
            } else {
                newFragment = new Welcome();
            }
            FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
            ft1.replace(R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) 
        About aboutFrag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.layoutAbout);
        aboutFrag.changeData(data);     
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37.5sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnList"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/list_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/action_settings" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/about_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="37.5sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i would suggest being more descriptive than "can't access my fragment", and perhaps posting some code demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> findFragmentById(int id)
>
> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when
>   inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.

you are adding fragments dynamically, so you should use the id of fragment container to find the fragment ie,

```
About aboutFrag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
```

my suggestion is to find the fragments by using the tag, respective tags are set while adding each fragment to the fragment container. for example,

```
Welcome myFragment = new Welcome();
ft.add(R.id.content, myFragment,"welcome tag");
ft.commit();
```

or

```
FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
ft1.replace(R.id.content, aboutFrag ,"about tag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and finding the fragment using findFragmentByTag(String tag) method.

```
About aboutFrag = fm.findFragmentByTag("about tag");

Welcome myFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("welcome tag");
```

I hope this helps you someway.